# Can I initialize tornado IOLoop.instance before forking new processes?

Tags: python, multiprocessing, tornado

Can I initialize an IOLoop.instance and than fork new processes, which uses IOLoop.instance()?
Something like:

```
#some code which initializes IOLoop.instance()           (1)
storage - Storage()
...
def f(storage):
    """some ioloop worker, which uses IOLoop.instance()"""
    storage.db_client.send(some value)
    ...

p1 = Process(target=f, args=(storage,))
p2 = Process(target=f, args=(storage,))
```

The [IOLoop documentation](http://tornado.readthedocs.org/en/latest/ioloop.html) doesn't says anything about usage IOLoop with multithreading, but [tornado.process.fork_processes documentation](http://tornado.readthedocs.org/en/latest/process.html#tornado.process.fork_processes) forbids initializing IOLoop before forking.

The point is that the code in (1) creates `storage` object, which is used by function `f`. The `storage` contains asynchronous database client which is suppose to use the same ioloop as the worker process.

Comment: Why specifically are you attempting to implement it like this? (Keep in mind that Tornado has built is multiprocessing support.)

Comment: I know about `tornado.process.fork_processes` but it literaly forbids initializing IOLoop instance before using it. From the project perspecive it is good to have `storge` object as a dependency, than to create it inside workers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After [asking](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/python-tornado/XZdAtVnt3ng) on tornado user group, I received answer, that I can't use IOLoop created by the parent process in child process.
The solution is very simple:

```
def f(storage):
    """some ioloop worker, which uses IOLoop.instance()"""
    # worker code starts here
    del IOLoop._instance

    # here we can safe use IOLoop
    IOLoop.instance().add_callback(...)
    storage.db_client.send(some value)
```

Comment: Using Tornado 3.2.2, I had to use `IOLoop.clear_current()` together with a conditional `if hasttr(IOLoop, '_instance'); del IOLoop._instance` to get this to work.